# Sequence of probabilities

Tags: probability, self-study

The probability distribution of a random variable X is $P(X=k)=p_k,k=0,1,2,...$ and $\frac{p_k}{p_{k-1}}=a+\frac{b}{k}$.
If $p_0=\frac{1}{9},p_1=p_2=\frac{4}{27}$,what can be said about the sequence of probabilities ${p_0,p_1,p_2,...}$

My attempt:Putting the values of $p_0,p_1,p_2$ in $\frac{p_k}{p_{k-1}}=a+\frac{b}{k}$,we get $a=\frac{2}{3},b=\frac{2}{3}$

But is the sequence are terms of any A.P. or G.P. or any known sequence?

Comment: Just a note for readers who may not have seen this class before -- the class of distributions with a recurrence in the pmf of the form $\frac{p_k}{p_{k-1}}=a+\frac{b}{k}$  has [been studied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28a,b,0%29_class_of_distributions) and encompasses the negative binomial ($a>0$), the binomial ($a<0$) and the Poisson ($a=0$). One important application is that it allows for a simple recursive calculation of pmfs for discrete compound distributions with number of terms, $N$, drawn from this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the infinite sequence here will be:

$$
p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots,p_n,\ldots
$$

Given the values:

$$
\frac{1}{9},\frac{4}{27},\frac{4}{27},\frac{32}{243},\frac{80}{729},\ldots
$$

As far as I know, this sequence belongs to none of the following progressions: arithmetic, geometric or harmonic progression. In fact,

for $k \in{1,2,3,\ldots}$ we have:
$$
p_k =p_{k-1} \left(a+\frac{b}{k}\right)  
$$

The common sequence of this progression $\left(a+\frac{b}{k}\right)$ varies with $k$ and when $k$ tends toward infinite, the ratio of  $\frac{p_k}{p_{k-1}}$ will converge toward $a=\frac{2}{3}.$